# C format code for positive and negative float numbers

Tags: c, printf

How can I force `printf` format codes like `%f` to produce aligned padded output for both positive and negative numbers. The following program is a minimal yet complete example of my problem:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int    step =    1;
    float score =  0.1;
    float phi   =  0.1;
    float rho   =  0.2;
    printf(" # score phi  rho\n");
    printf("%2d %2.3f %1.2f %1.2f\n", step, score, phi, rho);

    step++;
    score++;
    phi++;
    rho++;
    printf("%2d %2.3f %1.2f %1.2f\n", step, score, phi, rho);

    step++;
    score -= 1.2;
    phi++;
    rho++;
    printf("%2d %2.3f %1.2f %1.2f\n", step, score, phi, rho);

    return 0;
}
```

and here is the result:

```
 # score phi  rho
 1 0.100 0.10 0.20
 2 1.100 1.10 1.20
 3 -0.100 2.10 2.20
```

I wanted to have an output like

```
 #  score phi  rho
 1 +0.100 0.10 0.20
 2 +1.100 1.10 1.20
 3 -0.100 2.10 2.20
```

or

```
 # score phi  rho
 1 0.100 0.10 0.20
 2 1.100 1.10 1.20
 3 -0.10 2.10 2.20
```

**My current bad solution** is an `if-else` statement conditioned on the sign of *score* variable to choose from two different `printf`s for plus and minus signs.

Comment: Yes, not enough field width. `%2.3f` is doomed to fail, since the 3 decimal places plus the point will always be wider than the `2` width specified. Time to read the [man page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx)?

Comment: @xing It was that easy! Hoh!

Answer (score 4):

From the [format specification syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019), the `printf` conversion specification follows

```
%[flags][width][.precision][size]type
```

So, if we set the flag directive to `+`, sign (+ or -) appears as a prefix of the output value. For example,

```
printf("%+5.2f\n%+5.2f\n", -19.86, 19.86); // prints -19.86 \newline +19.86
```

Comment: `2.2`? What is the first `2` for? Digits before the comma, comma and digits after the comma all count into width. So if precision is 2, the number will have at least a comma and two digits after the comma, so at least 3 characters. So width of 2 is just ignored, the field is going to be at least widther then 3. Maybe `%+5.2f`?

Comment: @KamilCuk You're right! The width is optional and it'll be ignored in this case. As suggested by you, I changed it to the enough width for the above example. Also, from the man page, a small width never causes the value to be truncated. So, we can completely ignore the width and use something like `+.2f`. Thanks for your comment.